# Fullcalendar return event with null end value in eventClick if event have rrule

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

https://codepen.io/SashaPl/pen/MWboodq?editors=0010

If i have event with rrule then in eventClick it wont have end value, but will have correct start value.

For event like this end date will be Thu Feb 04 2021 00:00:00

```
{
        title: "simple event",
        start: "2021-02-02",
        end: "2021-02-04"
},
```

but for like this it will be null

```
{
        title: "event with rrule",
        start: "2021-02-03T12:30:00",
        end: "2021-02-03T13:30:00",
        rrule: "FREQ=Weekly;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20210804T000000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE"
}
```

Comment: If you believe this is a bug please report it to fullCalendar. There's nothing we can do about it here. We can help you with implementation issues but not with internal bugs in the library. Instructions for reporting bugs are here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: @ADyson yes, i report it, but i thought maybe someone faced the same problem and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to issue https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6172

you should set the `duration` property for event with rrule for getting `event.end` value in eventClick

https://codepen.io/acerix/pen/wvorZVP?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for me adding eventLengthTimeStamp to eventLengthTimeStamp when mapping events from backend

```
const eventLengthTimeStamp = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
```

when in even

```
 eventClick: (event) => {
  const popover = this._popoversMap.get(event.el);
  if (popover) {
    //this property is used because event with rrule have no end. end is null
    const diffTimeStamp = event.event.extendedProps.eventLengthTimeStamp;
    const end = new Date(event.event.start.getTime() + diffTimeStamp);
    const calendarEvent: EventApi = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.event));
    calendarEvent.extendedProps.end = end;
    popover.instance.popover.open({ event: calendarEvent });
  }
},
```

that's works fine for me